# Aperture previews not showing up using shared aperture library

Tags: aperture

My wife and I both have our own user profiles on a shared MBP, I have also set up Aperture to look at a library within the shared user folder and we both have full read/write permissions. The problem is that if I add new photos to the library on my user profile, my wife is unable to view the thumbnail previews that aperture creates, they just come up as black squares. If she clicks on one of the black squares, the image opens as normal.

Can somebody advise on what changes I need to make to get the previews to show correctly for both users?

Comment: I am new to Aperture but seems to be having the exact same problem - did you manage to find a solution? I do have one project/folder in Aperture where the thumbnail previews are visible in both user accounts (using the same Aperture lib from a shared folder), but the ones I import now only have visible thumbnails for the user importing the pictures.
I think I might have imported the project where it works in one account, before I even tried to open Aperture from the other account - but I'm not sure about this. I didn't really think about it until I realized new imports weren't working as expec